# How to compare fragment name to current month using kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

If the current month is January, fragment January opens.
else if the current month is February, fragment February opens.
else if and so on.

Comment: Post your code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can post this simple "when" to open fragment when you need to open fragment by month

```
when(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH)){
            0 -> {
                //TODO OPEN FRAGMENT
            }
            1 -> {
                //TODO OPEN FRAGMENT
            }
            2 -> {
                //TODO OPEN FRAGMENT
            }
            3 -> {
                //TODO OPEN FRAGMENT
            }
            4 -> {
                //TODO OPEN FRAGMENT
            }
            5 -> {
                //TODO OPEN FRAGMENT
            }
            6 -> {
                //TODO OPEN FRAGMENT
            }
            7 -> {
                //TODO OPEN FRAGMENT
            }
            8 -> {
                //TODO OPEN FRAGMENT
            }
            9 -> {
                //TODO OPEN FRAGMENT
            }
            10 -> {
                //TODO OPEN FRAGMENT
            }
            11 -> {
                //TODO OPEN FRAGMENT
            }
}
```

or you can retrieve month name from array of names and get fragment by classname that includes your month

Comment: I am new to android development . I dint know my question is clear or not but you understand my question and gave the code. Thank You.